# How much time should I spend on Graduate level problem?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am reading Multiplicative Number Theory Montgomery, Vaughan. Some problems are relatively easy for me and I solve them in a few minutes. However, some problems seems much harder and I could not solve for hours. Is it normal to spend much time on one problem?
Also, I am reading Analytic Number Theory Iwaniec, Kowalski. Problems in this book are very hard for me. I can solve only few of them. In many problems, I do not see connection between theorems in the book and given problem. How can I deal with it? Please answer my two questions with explanations. I need advice. Thank you

Comment: This is probably too general for an answer on MO.  It would be better to discuss with your advisor.

Comment: Spending a few hours on a problem from a graduate textbook is not too much. Spending a week is probably too much. In that case look up the solution or ask a mentor/colleague/friend. BTW solving these problems will reduce the average time spent on each problem. Part of graduate school is to learn persistence and the fact that doing mathematics takes a lot of time. I voted to reopen this question.